# Android take picture without SurfaceHolder

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

When trying to take a picture from a Service (no GUI), on some devices, I get a RuntimeException. However if I take a picture from an Activity using a SurfaceHolder, it will work.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
SurfaceView mview = new SurfaceView(context);
camera.setPreviewDisplay(mview.getHolder());
camera.startPreview();
camera.takePicture(null,null,iccb);
```

This sequence works fine on most devices but, in particular, on Motorola Droid, the call to takePicture method (actually the native method) will throw a RuntimeException. Also tried camera.setPreviewDisplay(null), but it won't work either.

However, if I use real SurfaceView from an Activity it also works fine on the Droid but I would need to do it from a background service.

Do you think that this behavior is shown due to privacy reasons so that noone can take pictures without actually displaying the image? This makes no much sense to me because I could load up a dummy activity with a 0 size preview and it works but I'd love not having to do it.

LogCat output:

```
10-24 12:20:57.838 D/CameraHal(267): hardware/ti/omap4/omap3/camera-omap4/src/CameraHal.cpp:189 enableMsgType - Preview callback not enabled 1c2
10-24 12:20:57.838 E/CameraHal(267): hardware/ti/omap4/omap3/camera-omap4/src/CameraHal.cpp:2448 takePicture - takePicture called with image buffer 0x0
10-24 12:20:57.838 D/AndroidRuntime(29248): Shutting down VM
10-24 12:20:57.838 W/dalvikvm(29248): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e560)
10-24 12:20:57.846 E/AndroidRuntime(29248): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 12:20:57.846 E/AndroidRuntime(29248): java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
10-24 12:20:57.846 E/AndroidRuntime(29248): at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
10-24 12:20:57.846 E/AndroidRuntime(29248): at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:829)
10-24 12:20:57.846 E/AndroidRuntime(29248): at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:793)
```

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: please add the stack trace of your exception and also read the logcat output very carefully, esp. the Motorola Droid logs a lot of useful informations if the camera is accessed.

Comment: Thanks @HefferWolf for your answer. 
Yes sorry, this is the stack trace:

java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
       at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
       at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:829)
       at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:793)

Answer (score 1):

It's a security issue. You shouldn't be alowed to use the camera without hacing a preview view. This should prevent malicious use of camera without the knowledge of the user, for example for spying purposes.

Comment: Well that's what I imagined. Motorola might have implemented such a thing for privacy reasons. Anyways, would be nice to know if there's another workaround rather than setting up a 0 size preview on a dummy activity.

Comment: It's not Motorola who has implemented it, but every one else who didn't conform to the guidelines :)

Comment: hehe thanks for pointing it out :)
I edited my post with the LogCat output. Do you still think that the reason if the lack of an actual preview?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this information? Also, is this still how the things are?

Comment: Seems that the new camera2 (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) API is more flexible, I will check it out on a real device, and modify the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems most of the modern Android devices now check that a `SurfaceView` exists and has a non-zero width and height (my Samsung Galaxy SII spews warnings in such a circumstance and won't capture the photo). Interestingly if the `SurfaceView` has a width and height of `1dip` then it works just fine.

```
<SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surface_view"
    android:layout_width="1dip"
    android:layout_height="1dip" />
```

With a width and height of 1 pixel the `SurfaceView` is incredibly difficult to see and whilst it works, it still falls into the category of "security issue".